# Catching Illegal JSON POST Data in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

When creating a POST request with valid JSON, the bodyParser parses the body of the POST request correctly. However, if I submit an invalid JSON string as the body, I receive the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>(/home/.../middleware/bodyParser.js:69:15)
...
```

So, it appears that the body parser is failing during the parsing of the body. However, I would like to catch this failure and return an error. I'm unsure what I can do to catch it, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is in the [connect.js bodyParser middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js).  It DOES do a try/catch and then calls next(err).  You should be able to catch this error and handle with additional custom code using the `app.error()` callback hook.  http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I've tried that to no avail. It seems as if the app.error is never being executed. I've tried: `app.error(function(err,req,res,next) { console.log("ERR"); });`, but it isn't being executed. For my app.configure for development, I have it set as `app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));`. I'm running node 0.4.9, connect 1.7.1, and express 2.4.6. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Try commenting out the express errorHandler for now and just putting your app.error call after your app.use routes are configured.  But other than that I'm not sure why `app.error` wouldn't get called.

Comment: For some reason, when using express/connect, JSON.parse doesn't throw exceptions, which is why your error handler doesn't fire. I'm investigating a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when using express/connect, JSON.parse doesn't throw exceptions, which is why your error handler doesn't fire.

I've [logged an issue with express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/872) to find out what's going on, but in the meantime you can use this workaround:

```
express.bodyParser.parse['application/json'] = function(data) {
  var result = JSON.parse(data)
  if (typeof result != 'object') {
    throw new Error('Problems parsing JSON')
  }
  return result;
}
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

update: this issue is not familiar to the author of express, so I am wondering if it's another library causing it. Will have to dismantle my code piece by piece to figure out where this behaviour is being introduced.

Comment: I see that the issue isn't related to express. Weird. Were you able to isolate the trouble code in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your

app.use(express.bodyParser());
after 
app.use(express.errorHandler(...))

solved it for me.

You may also adapt the following code to manage the error

```
express.bodyParser.parse['application/json'] = function(req, options, fn){
  var buf = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  req.on('data', function(chunk){ buf += chunk });
  req.on('end', function(){
  try {
    req.body = buf.length
      ? JSON.parse(buf)
      : {};
    fn();
  } catch (err){
    fn(new Error('Problems parsing JSON'));
  }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

bodyParser must be above app.use(app.router), it doesn't matter relative location to error handler as Perki